# c++ Friend function not recognised as friend with template specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, friend, specialization

I am trying to declare a function as friend to a class template with a protected member. Below is a minimal example.

```
template<int N> class myClass{
public:
    friend void f(const myClass& c);
protected:
    int a;
};
```

If I now define the function as

```
template<int N> void f(const myClass<N>& c){
    std::cout << c.a;
};
```

Then it works.

However if I use template specialisation

```
template<int N> void f(const myClass<N>& c);
template<> void f<1>(const myClass<1>& c){
    std::cout << c.a;
};
```

It does not recognise `f` as a friend anymore and complains that `a` is a protected member.

Why is that happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you say "it works" it does not actually work https://godbolt.org/z/93E6q1vr9. The error is the same. Please do include the error message in the quesiton. It should be rather clear about whats wrong

Comment: Because `friend void f(const myClass& c);` is a **nontemplate** friend declaration. That is, it befriends a nontemplate free function.

Comment: Neither of these will work once you actually try to use the function. The compiler will probably also warn you why. You are not declaring the same overload as `friend` as you are defining later. Make sure the declarations match: `template<int M> friend void f(const myClass<M>&);`

Comment: Indeed you are right. I was not getting any warning in the first case, but I did not actually try to run the function. When I did neither worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the friend declaration `friend void f(const myClass& c);` is a **nontemplate friend declaration**. That is, you're actually befriending a nontemplae free function. This is exactly what the warning tells you:

```
 warning: friend declaration 'void f(const myClass<N>&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
   12 |     friend void f(const myClass& c);
```

---

To **solve** this you need to *add a separate parameter clause* for the friend declaration as shown below:

```
template<int N> class myClass{
public:
    template<int M>        //added this parameter clause
    friend void f(const myClass<M>& c);
protected:
    int a;
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sMqM5bEYh)